# A question on $\pi-\lambda$ system

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading Rick Durett's Probability Theory and Examples. In the proof of the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem i.e If $\mathcal{P}$ is  a $\pi-$system and $\mathcal{L}$ is  a $\lambda-$system that contains $\mathcal{P}$ then $\sigma(\mathcal{P}) \subset\mathcal{L}$

My question is not directly related to the proof . The author tries to prove that a given set $C$ is closed under intersection . He says that the intersection property is equivalent to the following $$\mathcal{G}_A=\{B:A \cap B \in C\}$$ If $A \in C \implies \mathcal{G}_A \in C $

**My confusion lies here:According to me $A \in C \implies$   $\mathcal{G}_A  \in C$means that if $A \in C$ and $A\cap B \in C \implies B \in C $** but this is not the same as saying $C$ is closed under intersection or is it?
Thanks

Comment: Actually, the intersection property is equivalent to $$A\in C\implies\mathcal G_A\supseteq C,$$ not to what you write.